# MKMapSnapshotter how to set pin Image

Tags: ios, objective-c

My code to create pin image as follows:

```
 MKMapSnapshotOptions *options = [[MKMapSnapshotOptions alloc] init];
options.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation, 300, 300) ;
options.size = CGSizeMake(320,180);
options.scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

MKMapSnapshotter *snapShotter = [[MKMapSnapshotter alloc] initWithOptions:options];

[snapShotter startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKMapSnapshot *snapshot, NSError *error) {
    //
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"err = %@",[error description]);
    }

    UIImage *img = snapshot.image;

    MKAnnotationView *pin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:nil reuseIdentifier:nil];
    CGPoint coordinatePoint = [snapshot pointForCoordinate:userLocation];


    coordinatePoint.x += pin.centerOffset.x - (CGRectGetWidth(pin.bounds) / 2.0);
    coordinatePoint.y += pin.centerOffset.y - (CGRectGetHeight(pin.bounds) / 2.0);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(img.size, YES, img.scale);
    {
        [img drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
        [pin.image drawAtPoint:coordinatePoint];
        _imgViewMapThubbnail.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    _imgViewMapThubbnail.layer.cornerRadius = 10 ;
    _imgViewMapThubbnail.layer.masksToBounds = true ;

}];
```

This code is normal red pin and location is almost right. I want my custom pin so I added the code as below

```
pin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MY_IMAGE_NAME"];
```

Pin image is changed, and its working fine. However, my location has some difference. I don't know, how to adjust my code or pin image size to set it to right location?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that this is an old question, for anyone that came here for custom pin image, here's a revised code from the above sample that would render the pin the right location.

```
CGPoint coordinatePoint = [snapshot pointForCoordinate:newCenter];
    UIImage *pin = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin"];
    CGPoint centerOffset = CGPointMake(0, -pin.size.height / 2);
    coordinatePoint.x += centerOffset.x - (pin.size.width / 2.0);
    coordinatePoint.y += centerOffset.y - (pin.size.height / 2.0);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(img.size, YES, img.scale);
    {
        [img drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
        [pin drawAtPoint:coordinatePoint];
        _imgViewMapThubbnail.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```